# Delay receiving flight ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, online-resources, payment

I booked tickets with Flight hub on Feb 28, 2023. But I haven't received any confirmation yet. Does anybody know how long it will take normally?

Comment: Don’t know Flight Hub, but usually tickets get confirmed within seconds, minutes at most. Did you get a reference number when you booked? Can you access the “My bookings” section on their site? Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Yes. It says ticket is in process. I am experience this issue for the first time

Comment: Your best bet is to get in touch with flighthub directly. And maybe even block the card payment.

Comment: Did anything come out of this? I have the same situation

Answer (score 2):

> Does anybody know how long it will take normally?

Normally it takes just a few minutes.

More than 24 hours is a sure sign that something is wrong here. Most reservation system time out after 24 hours if the booking doesn't complete.

Things to do:

- Check the "my bookings" system on their website. See if anything is there. Specifically is there a PNR (6-digit letter/number).
- If there is a PNR go to the airline's website and check whether that PNR is life
- Check your credit card and see if there is a charge pending or a charge that went through.

Your next step depends on what you find. If your credit card is clean, than most likely the booking didn't go through and you can just ignore the whole thing. If there is hold (i.e. "pending") but no actual charge, then the booking is stuck in limbo. You will have to call (good luck with that). If your credit card  got actually charged you will also need to call and ask them.

You can also try to cancel on their website and see what happens.

Lesson learned: It's almost always best to book directly with the airline. In rare cases an online travel agent (OTA) such as FlighHub can offer substantial discounts but this comes at a substantial risk. OTA booking are MUCH MUCH more difficult to manage than direct bookings. The OTA will say "talk to the airline" and the airline will say "talk to the OTA".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I called their phone and they "processed" it right away and sent me the confirmation. Looks like they have bugs in their booking system sometimes.